# Is there way to construct a Q object, that represents a EmptyQueryset, i.e. that always returns an empty result?

Tags: python, django, django-q

In django I want to retrieve objects from the database depending on the attributes of some other objects. If one of the other objects doesn't exist, it should not influence the result of the query. The code is like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
try:
    objectA = MyModel.objects.get(id = idA)
    qA = Q(foo = objectA.bar)
except MyModel.DoesNot.Exist:
    qA = Q(???)
try:
    objectB = MyModel.objects.get(id = idB)
    qB = Q(abc = objectB.xyz)
except MyModel.DoesNot.Exist:
    qB = Q(???)
result = MyOtherModel.objects.filter(qA | qB, **other_filter_conditions)
```

For Querysets there is the `none()` method, which always returns the EmptyQueryset. Is there something similar for Q objects?

Or is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: What is the relationship between `MyModel` and `MyOtherModel`.  Isn't this just a `mymodel__foo = idA` or `mymodel__abc = idB` sort of query?

Comment: @S.Lott: No, the Q objects are much more complicated than in the example.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  What is the relationship between `MyModel` and `MyOtherModel`.  While the filters may be complex, it may also be possible to simplify slightly using the  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships techniques.

Comment: @S.Lott: Admitted, you're right. The logic is something like this: One appointment is cancel. Now I want all future appointments that can/should be rearranged and meet these conditions: `(`There is a appointment immediately preceding the cancellation `and` the appointment categories are compatible `and` the future appointment fits in the gap `) or (` there is a next appointment `and` the categories are compatible `and` the appointment to be moved fits the gap *exactly*`)`. I have no idea how to express that in a usual query, and Ignacios solution works perfectly. Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: Please **update** the question with the more complete data model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qList = []
try:
  objectA = ...
  qList.append(Q(foo=objectA.bar))
except ...:
  ...
 ...

result = MyOtherMdel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, qList),
  **other_filter_conditions)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> For Querysets there is the none() method, which always returns the EmptyQueryset. Is there something similar for Q objects?

Q(pk=-1)